# how can i change dropdown menu to open on click instead of hover?

Tags: php, css

I have multiple dropdown menu opens on buttons hover, I need the menu to open on button click and stay open till I press another button I tried almost every posple way but no use I appreciate any help this is my PHP code:

```
                    <div class="dropdown hidden-xs" >
                  <button <?php if ($tk_c == 'gift_card') ?> class="dropbtn"><?php echo                     
                $lang_gift_card; ?></button>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a <?php if (($tk_m == 'add_gift_card'))?>href="<?=base_url()? 
                >gift_card/add_gift_card"><?php echo $lang_add_gift_card; ?></a>
                  <a <?php if (($tk_m == 'list_gift_card'))?>href="<?=base_url()? 
                >gift_card/list_gift_card"><?php echo $lang_list_gift_card; ?></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="dropdown hidden-xs" >
                <button <?php if ($tk_c == 'sales') ?> class="dropbtn"><?php echo $lang_sales; ?> 
                </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a <?php if (($tk_m == 'list_sales'))?>href="<?=base_url()?>sales/list_sales"><?PHP 
                  echo $lang_today_sales; ?></a>
                  <a <?php if (($tk_m == 'opened_bill'))?>href="<?=base_url()?>sales/opened_bill"><? 
                  php echo $lang_opened_bill; ?></a>
                  </div>
                 </div>
```

And this is my css:

```
        <style>
    .dropdown-content a {
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          color: black;
          padding: 12px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
        }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
          display: block;
        }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
          background-color: #3e8e41;
        }
    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        div.pc {
        display: none;
         }
            }
    </style>
```

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript for what you are trying to do. If you are using jQuery, I would do something like this :

```js
$('#myDropdownid').on('click', function (e) {
   $(this).addClass('open');
});
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
   $('#myDropdownid').removeClass('open');
});
```

And then change you :hover class in css to the open class :

```css
.dropdown.open .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown.open .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```